# React not rendering array after fetching data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
class MyAttendees extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AuthContext;

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      barcodesData: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchBarcodeData() 
  }

  fetchBarcodeData() {
    const { currentUser, GetBarcodesByUser } = this.context; // getting current user logged in and a function
    const uid = currentUser.uid; // uid of the user
    GetBarcodesByUser(uid) // this will return a array of string containing barcodes id
             .then( data => this.setState({ barcodesData: data }))
  }

  // force rerender
  forceUpdater() {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
          {
            // trying to render the array list 
            // this is not rerendering even after the barcodes is updated
            this.state.barcodesData.map((item) => {
              console.log("item: ", item)
              return <h1 key={item}>{item}</h1>
            })
          }
    </div>
    )
  }
}
export default MyAttendees;
```

```
    const GetBarcodesByUser = async ( uid: string ): string[] => {
        const data = await getBarcodesByUser(uid);
        return data;
    }
```

```
 export const getBarcodesByUser = async ( uid: string ): string[] => {
  const result = [];

  const q = query(collection(firestore, "qrcode"), where("uid", "==", uid));
  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot): string[] => {
    querySnapshot.forEach( document => {
      result.push( document.id )
    })
  })

  return result;
}
```

Things that I have tried

- at first I was using function approach with useEffect.
- I tried to use function to render array.
- I tried to use the fetching function inside componentDidMount() function
- Tried forceUpdate
  Any of the above method is not working

Comment: - did you export the class as `export default MyAttendees` - is your function `GetBarcodesByUser` actually resolving anything or its rejecting the promise

Comment: Can you share a playground link?

Comment: yes, I did. But forget to add it.

Comment: Acutally, AuthContext have apikeys so i can't add the full source code

Comment: no, the function `GetBarcodesByUser` do not return promise

Comment: as i can see the code you shared you are using `then` after calling `GetBarcodesByUser(uid)` it means it returns a promise. can you `console` inside `then` weather its giving you anything or its going to a `catch` block instead

Comment: on doing 'console.log("data: ", data)' I get ```data:  
Array []
​
0: "NyUadadadsxCR3zgI"
​
1: "lfOsdasdaqB0neGUSN"
​
2: "yYasdo8AP1czHEVz"
​
3: "zG8Lg2yasdasf3xphBfS"
​
length: 4```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% that was the entire console.log so my guess is you are mapping the wrong bit. Try changing your state to set like this

```
.then( response => this.setState({ barcodesData: response.data }))
```

Comment: array is something like this ```barcodes:  
Array(4) [ "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa", "asdfasdfasdfasdf", "yasdfasdfasdfasVz", "zafdsfasdfasdfasdfS" ]```

Comment: @RitikRanjan Can you console.log(data) on your api call and post that please
```
.then( data => { 
     this.setState({ barcodesData: data })
     console.log(data})
```

Comment: on doing 'console.log("data: ", data)' I get ```data:  
Array []
​
0: "NyUadadadsxCR3zgI"
​
1: "lfOsdasdaqB0neGUSN"
​
2: "yYasdo8AP1czHEVz"
​
3: "zG8Lg2yasdasf3xphBfS"
​
length: 4```

Comment: @RitikRanjan just updated my answer try that

Comment: For the record: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/332043

Comment: `response.data` is giving me error

Comment: What is the error? Also please post up your api call as I am pretty sure it is that now.

Comment: I have updated the code snip, and response.data is undefined